# i dont see hello packets in trace file

Tags: ns2

I am using AODV routing protocol for neighbor discovery in ns2 but the trace file does not show any hello packet. The trace file looks like :

```
s 1.000000000 _0_ AGT  --- 0 cbr 210 [0 0 0 0] ------- [0:0 1:0 32 0] [0] 0 0
r 1.000000000 _0_ RTR  --- 0 cbr 210 [0 0 0 0] ------- [0:0 1:0 32 0] [0] 0 0
s 1.000000000 _0_ RTR  --- 0 AODV 48 [0 0 0 0] ------- [0:255 -1:255 30 0] [0x2 1 1 [1 0] [0 4]] (REQUEST)
s 1.003750000 _0_ AGT  --- 1 cbr 210 [0 0 0 0] ------- [0:0 1:0 32 0] [1] 0 0
r 1.003750000 _0_ RTR  --- 1 cbr 210 [0 0 0 0] ------- [0:0 1:0 32 0] [1] 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

In default hello packets is in disable mode in AODV protocol.

You can enable hello packets by doing below things,

comment or remove the below lines from your aodv.cc  (ns-all-in-one/ns2.xx/aodv)

```
#define AODV_LINK_LAYER_DETECTION

#define AODV_USE_LL_METRIC
```

execute `make clean and make` in your terminal.

re execute your tcl.. now hello packets will printed in your trace file.

Comment: actually the code is #ifndef AODV_LINK_LAYER_DETECTION
      htimer.handle((Event*) 0);
      ntimer.handle((Event*) 0);
#endif and #ifndef AODV_LINK_LAYER_DETECTION
 drop(p, DROP_RTR_MAC_CALLBACK);
#else so should both the blocks be commented

Comment: can you post the commented lines?

Comment: /*#ifndef AODV_LINK_LAYER_DETECTION
      htimer.handle((Event*) 0);
      ntimer.handle((Event*) 0);
#endif // LINK LAYER DETECTION */

Comment: Whether you add comment lines or it's default?

Comment: No, the comments were not default,I added the comments

Comment: Have you compiled your ns? after adding comments.

Answer (score 0):

Sir,
I am using NS2.35 version, In that version the for file aodv.cc,following lines by default commented.

## define AODV_LINK_LAYER_DETECTION

## define AODV_USE_LL_METRIC

once, simulate the script not able to see hello msg in trace file